# adding mutiple namespace for a element in xml file using dom4j

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, dom4j

The XML file which need to generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<wrapper:MMSRMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wrapper="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01 MMSR_head.003.001.01_Wrapper.xsd">
  <header:AppHdr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:header="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
    <header:Fr>
        ...
     </header:Fr>
  </header:AppHdr>
</wrapper:MMSRMessage>
```

Two namespaces were added for the root element "wrapper:MMSRMessage",It has no problem.
The following is the Java code for it:

```
Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
Element wrapper = document.addElement("wrapper:MMSRMessage");  
wrapper.addNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        .addNamespace("wrapper", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01")
        .addAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01 MMSR_head.003.001.01_Wrapper.xsd");
```

However, when I add two namespaces for element "header:AppHdr", I get the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.dom4j.IllegalAddException: No such namespace prefix

using java code:

```
Element headerApp = wrapper.addElement("header:AppHdr");
    headerApp.addNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
             .addNamespace("header", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01");
```

I also have tried so:

```
Element headerApp = wrapper.addElement("header:AppHdr","urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01")
            .addNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

in this way the error does not occur, but the namespace "xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" can not be added for the element "header:AppHdr".

That's my first question at Stackoverflow. I hope I can get an answer hier :-)

Comment: The last attempt looks fine to create the element in the namespace. As for the namespace declaration `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` on the inner element, do you get an error trying to add it, or does it simply not show up when you serialize/write out your document? Obviously, as the parent element already has that same namespace declaration, a serializer might not write it out and that shouldn't change the semantics of the created XML.

Answer (score 0):

DOM4J generally offers too many ways to skin the cat. In this area, the confusion is increased because `Document#addElement(String, String)` and `Element#addElement(String, String)` do very different validations: In the first case you can add an element with a qualified name without having the prefix bound to a namespace and the element ends up having no namespace (this is a bug). In the second case you must have the prefix bound (correct).

All in all, I reccomend *not* using qualified element and attribute names (`prefix:local-name`) if you can avoid it. Instead, strictly separate the local name of the element or attribute and use properly declared `Namespace` and `QName` constructs. In your case:

```
    Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();

    Namespace xsi = Namespace.get("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    Namespace wrapper = Namespace.get("wrapper", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01");
    Namespace header = Namespace.get("header", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01");


    Element wrapperElement = document
            .addElement(new QName("MMSRMessage", wrapper))
            .addAttribute(new QName("schemaLocation", xsi), "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01 MMSR_head.003.001.01_Wrapper.xsd");
    Element headerApp = wrapperElement.addElement(new QName("AppHdr", header));
    headerApp.addElement(new QName("Fr", header));
```